# Error while converting to PDF

Tags: errors, lyx, pdf, typearea, convert

- **Edit**
  I am using Lyx version 2.3.2

Regarding @Mensch comment:

**This comes after I downloaded mikitex fonts for Hebrew, and tried to install and reinstall several times. in The past, using an older version of Lyx (2.2), I had no problem to convert files that contains Hebrew letters to PDF, but since I updated Lyx to version 2.3, it is no longer working.**

- *I suspect that the problem might be that the Hebrew fonts are not
  installed on the right folder. However, I do not know what is **the
  right folder**, as I looked it up as much as I could, tried multiply
  options -- ans yet -- it's not working.*
- while trying to convert a lyx doc (Verison 2.3.2-2) when Using HEBREW
  fonts, I'm getting this error:

  ```
  This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.6.25)  15 AUG 2019 16:22
  entering extended mode
  **./newfile13.tex
  (newfile13.tex
  LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
  Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
  File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  )
  \c@part=\count80
  \c@section=\count81
  \c@subsection=\count82
  \c@subsubsection=\count83
  \c@paragraph=\count84
  \c@subparagraph=\count85
  \c@figure=\count86
  \c@table=\count87
  \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
  \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
  \bibindent=\dimen102
  ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
  Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def"
  File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
  LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
  )) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
  Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
  \inpenc@prehook=\toks14
  \inpenc@posthook=\toks15
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\cp1255.def"
  File: cp1255.def 2004/02/20 v1.1b Hebrew input encoding file
  ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latin9.def"
  File: latin9.def 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
  )) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
  Package: babel 2018/11/13 3.27 The Babel package
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\switch.def"
  File: switch.def 2018/11/13 3.27 Babel switching mechanism
  )
  *************************************
  * Local config file bblopts.cfg used
  *
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg"
  File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
   babel
  ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\rlbabel.def"
  File: rlbabel.def 2005/03/30 v2.3h Right-to-Left support from the babel system 
  Hebrew language support from the babel system
  ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\hebrew.ldf"
  File: hebrew.ldf 2005/03/30 v2.3h Hebrew language definition from the babel sys
  tem Hebrew language support from the babel system
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
  File: babel.def 2018/11/13 3.27 Babel common definitions
  \babel@savecnt=\count88
  \U@D=\dimen103
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def")
  \bbl@dirlevel=\count89
  )

  Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
  (babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
  (babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
  (babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
  (babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 57.

  \l@hebrew = a dialect from \language0
  ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
  Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
  \l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
  \l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
  \l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
  )) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\lheenc.def"
  File: lheenc.def 2005/05/20 v1.2c 7-bit Hebrew font encoding (test version: sti
  ll liable to change)
  Now handling font encoding LHE ...
  ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LHE
  ) (newfile13.aux
  LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LHE+cmr on input line 6.
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\lhecmr.fd"
  File: lhecmr.fd 2005/05/20 v1.2c Hebrew default font (test version: still liabl
  e to change)
  )
  ! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
  nd.
  <to be read again> 
                     relax 
  l.6 \select@language{hebrew}

  I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
  so I will ignore the font specification.
  [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
  You might try inserting a different font spec;
  e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
  ```

  )
  \openout1 = `newfile13.aux'.

  ```
  LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LHE/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
      LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\cp1255.def"
      File: cp1255.def 2004/02/20 v1.1b Hebrew input encoding file
      )
      Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
      Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
      [1
  ```

  {C:/Users/NOA!!!/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (newfile13
      .aux) ) 
      Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
       1294 strings out of 492946
       15732 string characters out of 3135524
       81384 words of memory out of 3000000
       5225 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
       4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
       1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
       25i,4n,23p,182b,149s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
       
      Output written on newfile13.pdf (1 page, 1608 bytes).
      PDF statistics:
       11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
       0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
       1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

**and this error**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.6.25)  15 AUG 2019 16:22
entering extended mode
**./newfile13.tex
(newfile13.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\cp1255.def"
File: cp1255.def 2004/02/20 v1.1b Hebrew input encoding file
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latin9.def"
File: latin9.def 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2018/11/13 3.27 The Babel package
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2018/11/13 3.27 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\rlbabel.def"
File: rlbabel.def 2005/03/30 v2.3h Right-to-Left support from the babel system 
Hebrew language support from the babel system
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\hebrew.ldf"
File: hebrew.ldf 2005/03/30 v2.3h Hebrew language definition from the babel sys
tem Hebrew language support from the babel system
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2018/11/13 3.27 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def")
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 57.

\l@hebrew = a dialect from \language0
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\lheenc.def"
File: lheenc.def 2005/05/20 v1.2c 7-bit Hebrew font encoding (test version: sti
ll liable to change)
Now handling font encoding LHE ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LHE
) (newfile13.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LHE+cmr on input line 6.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\lhecmr.fd"
File: lhecmr.fd 2005/05/20 v1.2c Hebrew default font (test version: still liabl
e to change)
)
! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.6 \select@language{hebrew}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

)
```

\openout1 = `newfile13.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LHE/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-hebrew\cp1255.def"
File: cp1255.def 2004/02/20 v1.1b Hebrew input encoding file
)
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
[1

```
{C:/Users/NOA!!!/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (newfile13
.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1294 strings out of 492946
 15732 string characters out of 3135524
 81384 words of memory out of 3000000
 5225 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,23p,182b,149s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\NOA!!!\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/d
pi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on newfile13.pdf (1 page, 1608 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

[image: Error as it appears on my scrren]

Comment: Your log stops in the middle and it is unclear why but the typearea warning is harmless.

Comment: From you post below, it looks like you are using the legacy PdfLaTeX Hebrew and `babel` toolchain. Do you have to do this or can you switch to XeLaTeX with `polyglossia`, or better yet LuaLaTeX with `babel`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Jneven, you're using PDFLaTeX. Using this for Hebrew is a *pain*. It's old, not maintained, and difficult to get working. Using a modern engine like LuaLaTeX is much easier and gives much better results. I can post a Lyx example, but this is no good if you have to use PDFLaTeX as your engine.

Comment: how do i switch from PDFlaTeX to LuaLaTeX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Because you gave us no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can not help you exactly.

But your sentence

> This happened after writing some paragraph, but if I delete the
>   paragraph the file IS converting to PDF

is a pretty clear hint for you:

**exactly in that "some paragraph" is the error causing the issue you got.**

So please at last show us this paragraph or mutch better show us a small complete tex code we can test on our computers. Lyx can generate TeX-code, but i do not use lyx, I can not help you with that.

The **error** you think it is is only a **warning**, comming from the usage of outdated options for your used documentclass `scrbook` like:

```
\documentclass[BCOR7.5mm,12pt,DIV12,a4]{scrbook}
```

You should better use this

```
\documentclass[BCOR=7.5mm,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,paper=a4]{scrbook}
```

to get rid of that **warnings** ...

Comment: Eventually I uninstalled Lyx and mikitex and re-installed it, which solved the problem. 

but I still can't convert to PDF when using a 'Right to Left' language (like hebrew)

Comment: @Jneven Well without seeing any tex code with hebrew we can not help you more ...

Comment: Please check my Answer in the bottom of the page. thank you

Comment: @Jneven Well, your edited question still does not show a short compilable tex code. Without TeX code I can not help more, I do not use Lyx ...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to abandon the old `pdflatex` Hebrew toolchain. It's just not worth the hassle. Now `lualatex` and `babel` provide excellent support for Hebrew.

The only slight difficulty is that LyX does not support setting this up through it's user interface. You have to add things directly to the LaTeX preamble.

Here's a sample LyX file (**Update** to support inline Hebrew):

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default,main]{australian}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{hebrew}
\babelfont[australian]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[australian]{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Noto Serif Hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\L}[1]{\foreignlanguage{australian}{#1}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language australian
\language_package 
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format pdf5
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
English 
\family sans
English
\family default
.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang hebrew
עִבְרִית 
\family sans
עִבְרִית
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
English 
\family sans
English
\family default
.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
English 
\lang hebrew
עִבְרִית
\lang australian
 English
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang hebrew
עִבְרִית 
\lang australian
English
\lang hebrew
 עִבְרִית
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

[image: Lyx Window]

For clarity, here is the LaTeX file exported from Lyx:

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default,main]{australian}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{hebrew}
\babelfont[australian]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[australian]{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Noto Serif Hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\L}[1]{\foreignlanguage{australian}{#1}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
English \textsf{English}.

\selectlanguage{hebrew}%
עִבְרִית \textsf{עִבְרִית}

\selectlanguage{australian}%
English \textsf{English}.

English \R{עִבְרִית} English

\selectlanguage{hebrew}%
עִבְרִית \L{English} עִבְרִית\selectlanguage{australian}%

\end{document}
```

And the PDF output:

[image: PDF output]