# Writing Hebrew text with Lyx

Tags: xetex, lyx, hebrew

I'm beginner who is interested in learning Latex and I'm currently using Mac OS Catalina.

I decided to use Lyx for writing my lecture notes in Hebrew, so I'v downloaded Lyx. I managed to create files in english, but my problem was with Hebrew. After searching the internet, I realised that I have to  install XeTex, I downloaded XeTex and unzipped it. In Lyx settings I changed the language to Hebrew and In fonts I checked the box that says: Use non-Tex fonts(via XeTex/LuaTex) as in the pictures bellow:
[image]

[image]

But I got Package fontspec Error again:

[image]

Seems that I have a problem with installing the fonts properly, I appreciate every help and even any suggestions for a different way to write Hebrew with Latex.

Comment: use a font with hebrew glyphs as Linux Libertine O

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463415/11604

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504332/87678

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me with this links, actually I saw them before.